# Probability of Pressing Spacebar

Tags: probability, statistics

> What is the probability that the next key a user hits on a $51$-key
>   keyboard (*the keys being $26$ letters, one shift, one spacebar, one
>   return, one backspace, $8$ regular punctuation keys, $13$
>   numerical-special character keys.*) is a spacebar, given that he is
>   grammatically and syntactically correct (*hence eliminating the need to
>   use backspace.*)

This question has been bugging me since last night and although I've tried to work it out on my own with hypothetical input-values, I don't think my method is right.

Comment: There are a lot of different answers to this, depending on how close to the real world you want to be. For instance $1/50$ would be a supportable but obviously wrong response. To be accurate you'd have to know the distribution of characters in English text, but that would give the answer immediately, so I don't see where there's mathematical work to be done.

Comment: see, I'm not going random here. like you cannot place b or z and be done with it. no that'd be invalid. Spacebar is hit after a word is completed, or a comma, semi-colon etc has been placed. How would it go? like if I'm currently writing a single letter word (like a or I) then probability of a spacebar being the next key hit would be 1/(number of all punctuations+spacebar+return). But what if I'm writing a 2-letter word or a 10 letter word etc? do I have to construct a probability distribution and do stuff with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that the *next* key is the spacebar depends on what key has just ben hit. In English, a space is far more likely after an e or an s than after a q.  In fact, the probability of hitting a spacebar depends on a lot of the past history.

Assuming that you didn't mean this but just meant the overall probability of a character being the spacebar, I'd suggest estimating this probability as follows.  First, get a reasonably long sample of grammatical English text. Second, count the spaces in the sample. Third, count the total number of characters. Fourth, divide.

For a possibly more accurate estimate, repeat the preceding with several more samples of text.